# Error while using Google maps version 2

Tags: android, google-maps

Hey hai I am not able to get the maps loaded on my phone I get a error cannot open file for reading I have added google play service as library project; I have also added google play services jar to my project

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mapsdemo"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
        <permission
              android:name="com.example.mapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-feature
         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.mapsdemo.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="API KEY"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mapsdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

When I run this on my galaxy s3 which has Android 4.0.4 The log cat gives me an error :

Log cat
01-25 20:11:45.690: E/(23663): Can't open file for reading
01-25 20:11:45.690: E/(23663): Can't open file for reading

Please help out with this

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml, replace "...android:value="API KEY"/> with your own API_KEY. [Here is to get your API_KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

Comment: I didnt want to disclose my API key so i just put API key in that I have already put in my actual API key in that section

Comment: Before you run, you MUST set the build target as "Googel APIs" in Android 4.0.3, NOT Android 4.0.3 in eclipse. Please check it; project < properties < Android < select "Googel APIs" under Android 4.0.3,

Comment: I'm getting this on a Galaxy S3 too.  I'm working on new feature of my app CellViz (http://www.cellviz.com/), and everything worked fine with build and debugging on my old laptop.  Then, I switched laptops and set up my Eclipse/Android SDK environment on the new laptop, and I'm getting this same error when trying to execute the exact same code that worked fine on the previous laptop.  So, I'm guessing its an issue with the build tools/config.  I'll report back if I figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god..your "my MainActivity.java" is wrong. You did not write anything in it, so you get the failed. To display Google maps, AT LEAST your java code MUST include the following code, which is basic and initial settings;

**1.**Modify your " **my MainActivity.java**" such like as below;

This shows how to create a simple activity with a map and a marker on the map. Notice how we deal with the possibility that the Google Play services APK is not installed/enabled/updated on a user's device.

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

**2.**After modifying, press **ctrl+shft+ alphabet "o"** on your keyboard and save it, Run again~!.

NOTE:Before you run, you MUST set the build target as "Googel APIs" in Android 4.0.3, NOT Android 4.0.3 in eclipse. Please check it; project < properties < Android < select "Googel APIs" under Android 4.0.3,

Answer (score 0):

This error message is apparently a side-effect on the Samsung Galaxy S3 that occurs when you don't register the SHA-1 fingerprint of the digital certificate you're using to sign the Android application with the Google APIs console for the Android Maps API V2.

For example, I got this same error:

```
Log cat 01-25 20:11:45.690: E/(23663): Can't open file for reading
```

...after I switched to a new laptop and forgot to add the SHA-1 of the new debug certificate on that laptop to the Google APIs console.

To fix this on Windows for the debug certificate, open the command prompt, and then:

```
cd .android
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v
```

This will print out a bunch of text, and you'll want to copy the text after the `SHA-1:` output.

Then, follow the instructions [in the Android Maps API V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#creating_an_api_project) to add your SHA-1 fingerprint followed by a semicolon and your app package name to the Google APIs console.